# How to catch and handle a "No python at C:\<some_directory>" error

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

TL;DR I want to write a batch file that will do some stuff when a "No Python at " error is encountered

I develop and maintain several Python-based automation tools as my job and often, my users will encounter the dreaded "no Python at " error when the tool's virtual environment attempts to activate.  I include a batch file that fixes the problem with all downloads of my tools, and it works like a charm, but they currently have to run it manually.  I'd like to see if I can set things up so that the fix runs automatically when the error occurs.

Unfortunately, my skill at writing complex behavior in batch files is a bit lacking, and my Googling didn't turn up anything obvious for the tack I'm trying to perform.

Anyway, here's the batch file that runs the Python script:

```
"venv\Scripts\python.exe" Some_Python_Script.py
```

And here's what I want to run in the event of a "no Python at <path." error:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=@" %%a in (`where /r "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs" Python?3.??(64*`) do set pypath="%%a"
cd "%~dp0"
%pypath% "%~dp0\fixVenvConfig.py"
```

^^^The tools are run inside of a secure VM, and the geniuses who install Python on them for us never check the box to add Python to the system path, so I instead must locate a Python executable by following the shortcut in the start menu.  Once I have a usable Python interpreter, I pass its file path into a Python script that then fixes the config file of the virtual environment used by the automation tools.  I don't remember how *half* of the stuff in the above batch file script actually works.  I just know that it *does*, so I just don't touch it.

In the end, I'm trying to figure out how to make it so that if what's in the first code block results in a "no Python at " error, the code in the second block gets run, and then the first block gets tried again.  As previously mentioned, however, this is a bit beyond my level of batch file expertise.  Please help?

Comment: [this](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) may help - code `9009` refers to file not found errors

Comment: The people who installed Python for you are geniuses. Nobody should ever make changes to `%Path%`, it is not needed, and if your tools or script were written expecting it, then it's your fault for writing poor or non robust code. What is even worse, instead of determining the locations of `python.exe` files, you're now expecting to find and run a `.lnk` which expects that a Programs menu entry was always created at installation time, and has never since been removed, or a newer/preferred version installed since. It also does not know whether that shortcut has been modified, and just runs it!